# Newlines in CSV data - Python

Tags: python, csv, newline

The following block of code is my attempt at making a CSV filled with data about employees but I've noticed that newlines characters at the end of the last header and its respective data are messing with my searches in the data.

I've tried to use `'ab'` instead of '`a`' but I get a Type error asking for a bytes-type object and not a str type.

```
def write_csv(emp_json, licenseName):
    filePath='C:\Scripts\Python\data.csv'
    data = open(filePath, 'a') 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(data)
    count = 0
    for emp in emp_json:
        emp.update({'licenseName':licenseName})
        if count == 0:
            header = emp.keys()
            csvwriter.writerow(header)
            count += 1
        csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())
    data.close()
```

Any info on how to remove all newline characters from the headers and the data? Or how to create the data without newlines in the first place? Please comment if you need more information and context.

Thanks

Comment: You want to remove the newlines from the CSV file you're writing?

Comment: Are the newline characters in the emp_json dict you are writing to the CSV file? e.g. `emp['licenseName'] = 'someLicense\n'`

Comment: how does your json dictionary looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want no newlines, add `newline=""` as parameter to `open(...)`:

```
def write_csv(emp_json, licenseName):
    filePath='C:\Scripts\Python\data.csv'
    with open(filePath, 'a', newline="") as data: 
       csvwriter = csv.writer(data)
       count = 0
       for emp in emp_json:
           emp.update({'licenseName':licenseName})
           if count == 0:
               header = emp.keys()
               csvwriter.writerow(header)
               count += 1
           csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())
```

PS: use `with open(..)` for writing to csv it takes care of opening and closing the file for you.